# How to use a single trainable variable as an "Input" inside a keras tensorflow 2.0 model, broadcast across the whole batch?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

For example, how would you create a model that predicts the mean of outputs Y (no input X given).

The mean should be

```
mu = K.variable(1.0)
```

But that doesn't work.

For example:

```
keras.models.Model(outputs=K.variable(1.0))
```

does not yield a valid model.

**UPDATE:**

see here [How to create a tf.keras layer with no kernal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55697773/how-to-create-a-tf-keras-layer-with-no-kernal)

Comment: The model that predicts the mean of Y without X given? What is Y, X? (input, output) What is mu, mu0? Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: mu is almost always the estimated mean. X and Y are almost always the inputs and outputs. These basically do not need clarification to anyone who will know the answer in this context. Will add something but keep that in mind.