# How to create a tf.keras layer with no kernal, i.e. create a trainable variable that you can use anywhere in the keras model definition?

Tags: keras

For example, just want the bias. A scalar. No kernel.

Using model.add_weight on tf.Variable and K.variable fails.

This should be simple. Can not find it in the docs.

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be the best way I've come across so far:

```
class BiasLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim=1, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.V = self.add_weight(shape=(1,), initializer=keras.initializers.Constant(value=0), dtype=tf.float32, trainable=True)
        super().build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return x * 0 + self.V # this is stupid, is there a better way
        # return self.V # this does not work, results in no trainable variables

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

Comment: You can set the kernel value all 1s.

Comment: all zeros constant you mean?

Comment: I mean all ones constant.

Comment: That is the identity kernel. I am just trying to hack Keras to give me a bias variable to train as a separate variable nothing to do with anything else. I do not want to add extra train variables. 

If I could get Keras to deal with add_weight(tf.Variable(1.0) I wouldn't need this hack either.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `kernel_size=0`. I write a sample to demonstrate this.

## With normal kernel

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist


(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)


kernel_size=(5, 5)
# kernel_size = 0

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='same',
                        input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(layers.LeakyReLU())
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.fit(x_train, y_train,
#           batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1)
# model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
model.summary()
```

## The summary with kernel

[image]

## Without kernel

change the `kernel_size=5` to `kernel_size=0`

## The summary without kernel

[image]

Comment: OMG, so simple. Did not think that kernel size zero should work! Should be added to the docs as a quick/nice way to create variables.

Comment: I'm finding that this doesn't work for my case yet ... am only looking for a wrapped trainable variable, I think you are maybe solving some more complicated case where the zero choice propagates through the model.